# C# Chat Program Lidgren

Tags: c#, forms, networking

I wrote the following program that is suppose to start up, show the form and connect to the server and get an messages. However when I start it nothing happens?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Lidgren.Network;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsGame2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private NetClient client;
        private NetBuffer buffer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Connect()
        {
            NetConfiguration config = new NetConfiguration("xesh");
            NetClient client = new NetClient(config);

            client.Connect("75.127.105.216", 14242);

            NetBuffer buffer = client.CreateBuffer();
        }

        private void ReceiveMessages()
        {
            Connect();
            bool keepGoing = true;
            while (keepGoing)
            {
                NetMessageType type;
                while (client.ReadMessage(buffer, out type))
                {
                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case NetMessageType.DebugMessage:
                            Console.WriteLine(buffer.ReadString());
                            break;

                        case NetMessageType.StatusChanged:
                            Console.WriteLine("New status: " + client.Status + " Reason: " + buffer.ReadString());
                            break;

                        case NetMessageType.Data:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Update(string str)
        {
            ReceiveMessages();
            textBox1.AppendText(str + "\r\n");
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be calling the ReceiveMessages or Update methods?

Comment: What controls are in the form, how does the InitializeComponent() look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling your methods.

try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    ReceiveMessages();
    // or 
    Update("Me");
}
```

Do you have any buttons on your form? Kinda need a bit more information

Answer (score 2):

You have declared:

```
    private NetClient client;        
    private NetBuffer buffer;
```

However your Connect() method constructs new local **client** and **buffer** which will be out of scope when the method returns.  The instance's **client** and **buffer** never get initialized and there fore will not be meaningful when used in the ReceiveMessages() method.